# how to access rails instance variable(@theme) in custom.css.erb?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have Theme Model and I have 3 Field

1) navbar
2) header
3) contain

I want to access instance Variable (@theme) from custom.css.erb so how I can I access params.

**Controller.rb**

```
def show
 @params = params[:name].downcase
 @cmp = Company.find_by(name: @params)
 @theme = Theme.find_by(company_id:  @cmp.id)
end
```

**custom.css.erb**

```
<% if @theme.present? %>
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: <%= @theme.navbar %> !important;
}
.page-header {
    background-color: <%= @theme.header %> !important;
}
.panel.panel-flat {
    background-color: <%= @theme.contain %> !important;
}
.panel-heading {
    background-color: <%= @theme.contain %> !important;
}
<% else %>
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #37474F !important;
}
.page-header {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.panel.panel-flat {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.panel-heading {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
  }
```

I got Error Like Below.

[image]

Comment: u can assign the same in controller and use the instance variable right

Comment: yes I do code in Controller's Show method and when page load I want to check css colour from Model

Comment: You can't access params directly in a template. You need to get the value in your controller, declare it as an instance variable and then access the instance variable in the template.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic css styles which are using instance variables should not be put inside css.erb / css.haml as it wont work properly.
Consider asset precompilation.
Rails will precompile assets before starting application and there after it will be static resource. So, your dynamicity can't be achieved here

#### Solution:

Just put those dynamic css styles inside layout

**/layout/home.html.haml**

```
:css
  .div {
    color: <%=@mycolor%>;
    ...
  }
```

**/layout/home.html.erb**  ( If you have erb template)

```
<style type="text/css">  
.div {
   color: <%=@mycolor%>;
   ...
} 
</style>
```

Comment: ya, it's working already but if I want to use different CSS file for this so how can I?

Comment: @RonakBhatt any css that is common put in css file. And any dynamic classes put in layout as shown above